# Why doing someVar in someArray in an If always give false value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I was just working on something in AngularJS. I noticed that by using the attached style of if condition, I always get a false result. Why so? Am I missing something? I tried to google it but didn't find anything.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var allowedExtensions = [".jpg",".pdf", ".png"];
    var testExt = ".jpg";

    if(testExt in allowedExtensions){
       $scope.isAllowed = true;
    }else{
       //will always go here why?
       $scope.isAllowed = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Is Extension Allowed : {{isAllowed}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am from .NET background so we use LINQ in that kinda same like that. Is this type of syntax not supported in JS?

**EDIT**
I know about index of and other ways to find if it is in the array. But I was confused why in operator is not working.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: That's not what the `in` operator does. It checks to see if the string on the left side appears as a *property name* in the object on the right side.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: You probably want [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @Blauharley I know but I thought in will work in the same way as a search in an array.

Comment: @Pointy Ty for the info, I thought it would check if the array contains that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array, therefore `in` only works on indices or property name; from the docs:

> The `in` operator returns true` if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

Try `allowedExtensions.includes(testExt)` or perhaps `allowedExtensions.indexOf(testExt) != -1` instead.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for arrays, `in` is for objects

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var allowedExtensions = [".jpg",".pdf", ".png"];
    var testExt = ".jpg";

    if(allowedExtensions.indexOf(testExt) !== -1){
       $scope.isAllowed = true;
    }else{
       //will always go here why?
       $scope.isAllowed = false;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Is Extension Allowed : {{isAllowed}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointy called out, your syntax is simply incorrect. There are two main ways you can do this in JS.

## Array.indexOf [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var allowedExtensions = [".jpg",".pdf", ".png"];
var testExt = ".jpg";

if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(testExt) > 0){
  $scope.isAllowed = true;
} else {
  $scope.isAllowed = false;
}
```

## Array.includes [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
var allowedExtensions = [".jpg",".pdf", ".png"];
var testExt = ".jpg";

if (allowedExtensions.includes(testExt)){
  $scope.isAllowed = true;
} else {
  $scope.isAllowed = false;
}
```

You'll get better browser support with *indexOf*, but *includes* is a newer/cleaner solution.

Side-note, I always find in interesting in programming when someone says "if a is true then b is true, if a is false b is false". Rather than have redundant conditional blocks you could just directly assign the expression, since both expressions (indexOf & includes) return the type Boolean. 
e.g.

```
$scope.isAllowed = allowedExtensions.includes(testExt);
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about these but I didn't know about the in operator.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator i used to check for properties /keys.
 In your case you can use `Array.indexOf()`:

```
if(allowedExtensions.indexOf(testExt)) $scope.isAllowed = true;
```